# sum vectors in a matrix by distance from a cell (R)

Tags: r, matrix, matrix-multiplication

Suppose I have a matrix `A` of dimensions `n x m`. A starting cell `(i,j)`, And a constant `k` which satisfies `k < n x m`.

I need a way to extract the values inside `A` such that all values are within `k` steps from the starting cell. a step is either a column move or a row move.
Then Im looking to sum the extracted values by  2 groups where 1 group consists of sums obtained from the same column in the original matrix and the other group is the sum obtained from summation of values along rows of the original matrix.

It is important for me that this addresses situations where the starting cell is within `k` steps from the edge of the matrix.
Example set (I'm heavily simplifying here):

```
> #create matrix where m = 7,n = 7
> Mat <- sample(1:49,49) %>% matrix(7,7)
> 
> #declare starting cell where (i = 4, j = 2)
> i = 4
> j = 2
> 
> #declare number of steps
> k = 2
> 
> Mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
[1,]   25   35   29   10   16   46   23
[2,]   32   43    7    5   31    1   14
[3,]   36   19   49   45   13   41   47
[4,]   17   18   48    9    3   28   12
[5,]   26    6   30   33   20    2   11
[6,]   40   24   39   21   37   38    8
[7,]    4   15   34   22   27   44   42
> Mat[i,j]
[1] 18
```

for this example an output would be two vectors (one for column sums and one for row sums):

```
> Columnsum  <- c(sum(36,17,26) ,           #sum(Mat[3:5,1])
+                 sum(43,19,18,6,24),       #sum(Mat[2:6,2])
+                 sum(49,48,30),            #sum(Mat[3:5,3])
+                 sum(9))                   #sum(Mat[4:4,3])
> 
> Rowsum <- c(sum(43),                       #sum(Mat[2,2:2])
+             sum(36,19,49),                 #sum(Mat[3,1:3])
+             sum(17,18,48,9),               #sum(Mat[4,1:4])
+             sum(26,6,30),                  #sum(Mat[5,1:3])
+             sum(24))                       #sum(Mat[6,2:2])
>             
> Columnsum
[1]  79 110 127   9
> Rowsum
[1]  43 104  92  62  24
```

Comment: I' will add that i have tried rotating 4 binary triangular matrices of size n/2 x m/2 each and then binding them and multiplying them with the original matrix as a vector, this worked but seemed very inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could 'remove' parts of your matrix `Mat` with entries more than `k` steps away from `(i,j)` by overwriting them with `NA`:

```
Mat[abs(row(Mat) - i) + abs(col(Mat) - j) > k] <- NA
```

Then remove the rows and columns that are entirely `NA`:

```
Mat <- Mat[rowSums(is.na(Mat)) != ncol(Mat), colSums(is.na(Mat)) != nrow(Mat)]
```

And finally  you can compute the row and column sums:

```
Columnsum <- colSums(Mat, na.rm = TRUE)
Rowsum <- rowSums(Mat, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: This is great, In the first part setting values to 0 instead of NA actually lets us skip right to the last  stage. thanks for this solution!

Comment: that's true, but i figured you wanted to drop the columns and rows that were too far away. if you set to 0, then you'll get extra 0 values in your row and column sums

Comment: Right, I guess there is an added step of removing those 0's from the final vectors if I use 0's. Thanks again.